# Are there any publicly available BigQuery Google libraries for validating attribute names?

Tags: google-bigquery

Google's BigQuery system states that identifiers must meet and regular-expression syntax, specifically, [A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]* (as indicated here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical). In addition, while it is not explicitly stated, there is probably a length limitation as well. Finally, identifiers cannot match existing keywords.

I want to generate SQL queries based on user-input, but I also want to properly validate the queries before submitting them. I can cheat and back-tick all attribute names, but where a query can be simple, I prefer to keep it simple.

It's simple enough for me to check against the regular-expression and the possible length limitation, but checking against the keyword list requires that I have an up-to-date keyword list in hand.

So two questions:

1. Is there an existing library I can use to check an attribute name, or perhaps even a whole query?
2. If I cannot have the first item, can I get a publicly maintained list of keywords? (Yes, yes, I can scrape this together myself from the language spec, but my answer will be out of date the next time Google adds a new feature).

I am specifically targeting the BigQuery "Standard" SQL rather than the "Legacy" SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ..or perhaps even a whole query?

Yes, use the `dryRun` flag in your request. The query will not run, but it will be checked if it's syntactically correct.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query#dryRun

[image]

The error should also contain why the query is invalid.

Comment: Well, that's at least a start. Is there a way of making it work that does not require an internet connection? I want to be able to write unit tests with this capability, and for that, I prefer to use a Fake or Mock implementation of the BigQuery service interface.

Comment: No, you'd need to make the API call.